# SweepGradient change position of start and end color

Tags: android, canvas, sweepgradient

I want to create a CircleView with gradient from **bottom -> left ->  top -> right**.
So I using canvas with `SweepGradient` like this

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    int[] colors = {Color.GREEN, Color.RED};
    float[] positions = {0, 1};

    SweepGradient gradient = new SweepGradient(100, 100, colors, positions);
    paint.setShader(gradient);
    canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 100, paint);
}
```

[image]

But the default order of this is **right -> bottom ->  left -> top** but I want **bottom -> left ->  top -> right**
I have tried change the positions to

```
float[] positions = {0.25f, 1.25f};
```

but it only works in `Preview` of AndroidStudio, when I run in real device, it displays the result as same as `positions = {0, 1}`

How can I make `SweepGradient` gradient from `bottom -> left ->  top -> right` like this

[image]

**--- UPDATE ---**
We can use `setLocalMatrix` for `SweepGradient` like this for rotate the gradient

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(90, 100, 100);
gradient.setLocalMatrix(matrix);
```

[image]

Comment: use `Shader#setLocalMatrix(Matrix localM)`

Comment: @pskink unfortunately, `setLocalMatrix` only work perfect in Preview mode, in my real device API 19 it won't work

Comment: post your code then

Comment: @pskink I have update my code and the screenshot from real my device

Comment: @pskink I found the problem, setRotate(90) will not work in real device but setRotate(90,100,100); work. thank you so much

Comment: see http://pastebin.com/VeXnrNCE

Comment: @pskink I can not access to this pastebin, maybe it's private

Comment: Can not find the server's DNS address of pastebin.com. maybe pastebin is down in my country. I will check it late. if possible can you make an answer at stackoverflow

Comment: @PhanVanLinh Replace `matrix.setRotate(90);` to `matrix.postRotate(90, 100, 100);` and check.

Comment: @blizzard I check it and it work successful, I have a comment above. thank you so much ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rotate the canvas before drawing the circle.

```
public class CircleView extends View {
    private Paint paint;

    public CircleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        paint = new Paint();

        int[] colors = {Color.GREEN, Color.RED};
        float[] positions = {0, 1};
        SweepGradient gradient = new SweepGradient(100, 100, colors, positions);
        paint.setShader(gradient);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(90, 100, 100);
        canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 100, paint);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

Edit-1:
Alternative approach suggested by [@pkskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) is to use [`setLocalMatrix`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Shader.html#setLocalMatrix(android.graphics.Matrix)) like below:

```
public void init() {      
    int[] colors = {Color.GREEN, Color.RED};
    float[] positions = {0, 1};

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90, 100, 100);

    Shader gradient = new SweepGradient(100, 100, colors, positions);
    gradient.setLocalMatrix(matrix);

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setShader(gradient);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 100, paint);
}
```

Comment: Do you know another way to do it without rotate the canvas. In my project now, after I create `SweepGradient` I need to set it as background an ARC seekbar (https://github.com/neild001/SeekArc). For circle we can rotate, but for ARC seekbar we can not rotate

Comment: Sorry @PhanVanLinh I don't know other way, but Please create a separate post for the above question.